# How to get object for an inner bind class

Tags: java, guice, inject

I have a class which extends `JerseyServletModule`. This class is installing a module

sample class:

```
public class SampleJersey extends JerseyServletModule {
  // some bind statements
  install(new FirstModule());
  install(new MyConstrutorClass(/*need MyActualClass object as parameter*/)); // here I need to pass MyActualClass object to the constructor
}
```

Now this `FirstModule` installing another Module.

Ex:

```
public class FirstModule extends AbstarctModule{
   // some bind operations
   install(new SecondModule());
}
```

Now this `SecondModule` binding another class

Ex:

```
public class SecondModule extends AbstractModule {
  bind(MyActualClass.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
}
```

I have a class where I need to pass `MyActualClass` object as an argument to a `constructor`

Ex:

```
public class MyConstrutorClass{

   @Inject
   MyConstrutorClass(MyActualClass actual){
      // some functionality here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems like `MyConstrutorClass` is a Guice module. Modules *provide* things, `MyConstrutorClass` seems like something that you want to provide.

Now, you'vealready installed `SecondModule`, which provides `MyActualClass`. This means that all dependencies to `MyConstrutorClass` have already been provided. So there is nothing else to do: just `@Inject` `MyConstrutorClass` and you're done.